# Mongorestore keeps throwing "(NotMaster) not master" error at me

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongorestore

I am new to mongodb and I've been trying to restore my data from mongodump. Any time I try running the script in terminal, it executes nearly entirely, then reverts. I've tried looking around but solutions haven't touched on the **'not master'** issue

This is my mongorestore script; placeholders used for brevity

```
mongorestore --host 'the-given-shard.net:27017' \
  --ssl -u 'username' -p 'placeholder' --authenticationDatabase admin --db=loc8r \
  --collection=locations dump/loc8r/locations.bson
```

And this is the output

```
2020-02-04T17:30:21.817+0000    checking for collection data in dump/loc8r/locations.bson
2020-02-04T17:30:22.123+0000    restoring to existing collection loc8r.locations without dropping
2020-02-04T17:30:22.123+0000    reading metadata for loc8r.locations from dump/loc8r/locations.metadata.json
2020-02-04T17:30:22.124+0000    restoring loc8r.locations from dump/loc8r/locations.bson
2020-02-04T17:30:24.205+0000    [########################]  loc8r.locations  8.21KB/8.21KB  (100.0%)
2020-02-04T17:30:24.888+0000    [########################]  loc8r.locations  8.21KB/8.21KB  (100.0%)
2020-02-04T17:30:24.888+0000    finished restoring loc8r.locations (0 documents, 0 failures)
2020-02-04T17:30:24.889+0000    Failed: loc8r.locations: error restoring from dump/loc8r/locations.bson: (NotMaster) not master
2020-02-04T17:30:24.889+0000    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

Comment: "NotMaster" usually means you are connected to a secondary node that cannot take writes

Comment: As in my node I'm connecting from, or the server? And how do I connect to the master node then?

Comment: That is referring to the server.  If you have a replica set, use `--host replicaSetName/hostname:port`.  You can also connect to the node with the shell and run `db.isMaster()` to find out the current primary

Comment: It worked! The `db.isMaster()` did the trick; turns out I was on a secondary node all this while. Thanks a lot

Comment: It really is a better option to use the replica set name when connecting.  That way if the primary changes for any reason, the tool can automagically reconnect to the new primary.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, I really appreciate it; I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

`db.isMaster()` does not work for me when I follow

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/getting-started/

```
db.inventory.insertMany([    { item: "journal", qty: 25, status: "A", size: { h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" }, tags: [ "blank", "red" ] },    { item: "notebook", qty: 50, status: "A", size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: "in" }, tags: [ "red", "blank" ] },    { item: "paper", qty: 10, status: "D", size: { h: 8.5, w: 11, uom: "in" }, tags: [ "red", "blank", "plain" ] },    { item: "planner", qty: 0, status: "D", size: { h: 22.85, w: 30, uom: "cm" }, tags: [ "blank", "red" ] },    { item: "postcard", qty: 45, status: "A", size: { h: 10, w: 15.25, uom: "cm" }, tags: [ "blue" ] } ]);
```

and actually outputs:

```
uncaught exception: WriteCommandError({
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1615842692, 6),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not master",
    "code" : 10107,
    "codeName" : "NotMaster",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1615842692, 6),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}) :
WriteCommandError({
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1615842692, 6),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not master",
    "code" : 10107,
    "codeName" : "NotMaster",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1615842692, 6),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
})
WriteCommandError@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:417:48
executeBatch@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:915:23
Bulk/this.execute@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:1163:21
DBCollection.prototype.insertMany@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:326:5
@(shell):1:1
```